# AX 2012 Stack Trace Error On Purch Agreement form(Wrong Arugement Type For Function

Tags: stack

I had the same problem on Purchase Agreement Form. When I am trying to create a New Purchase Agreement from Purchase Agreement List form its throws me a stack trace error.Here is the stack Trace

```
  (C)\Classes\QueryRun\setRecord
    (C)\Classes\FormDataSource\last
    (C)\Classes\FormDataSource\linkActive
    (C)\Classes\FormRun\run
    (C)\Forms\PurchAgreement\Methods\run - line 12  (which is super())   
    (C)\Classes\FormFunctionButtonControl\Clicked
```

This stack is not stop me from Purchase agreement creation.I am able to click Ok and create Purch Agreement.When Tried to create a new Purch Agrement from AOT it doesn't throw any error.This error occurs in only some of our environments(but all the environment have same code surrounding Purch Agreement--I compared forms and classes from different Envs both working and not working)

Things I tried
1.Cleared Cache,AUC files and changed GUID ,Full Compile and Full CIL twice,AOS,SQL server restarts.
2.I tried both the methods which are changing the datasource Join Type property on PurchAgreement Task page to delayed and adding additional datasources to listpage which didn't help.

Is there any thing that you all would suggest other than these approches.Any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the Form PurchAgreementListPage on the MenuItemButton BtnNewPurchAgreement (ButtonGroup: NewGroup). There is a property called "CopyCallerQuery", if this is set to yes, switch it to Auto and the error will disappear. In the next Microsoft updates (I think KB2921583) this should be fixed.